# Vk api:users.get не работает

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь получить информацию о пользователе из vk, используя users.get, но он возвращает false, никаких  error'ов, access_token возвращается.

```
function _curl_get_contents($url, $vars = array(), $method = 'GET')
    {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            if ($method == 'POST')
            {
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($vars));
            }
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return json_decode($data);
    }
    if(empty($_GET['code'])) {
        header('location:https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id='.$client_id.'&scope=email&display=page&redirect_uri='.urlencode('http://***').'&response_type=code&v=5.28&state=3');
    } else {
        $data = _curl_get_contents('https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id='.$client_id.'&client_secret='.$client_secret.'&code='.$_GET['code'].'&redirect_uri='.urlencode('***'));
        $json = _curl_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids='.urlencode($data->user_id).'&fields=photo_200,city,verified&v=5.28&access_token='.urlencode($data->access_token));
        var_dump($json);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public function getUserInfo($user_id = false)
    {
        $user_id = ($user_id) ? $user_id : $this->accessToken['user_id'];
        $userInfo = Yii::app()->vk->request(
            $this->access_token,
            'users.get',
            array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'fields' => 'photo_200_orig,nickname,first_name,last_name,screen_name,sex,city,bdate',
            )
        );

        $user = array();

        $user['first_name']  = $userInfo['response'][0]['first_name'];
        $user['last_name']   = $userInfo['response'][0]['last_name'];
        $user['avatar']      = $userInfo['response'][0]['photo_200_orig'];
        $user['uid']         = $userInfo['response'][0]['id'];
        $user['sex']         = ($userInfo['response'][0]['sex'] == 1) ? 0 : 1 ; //0 - Ж, 1 - М (В ВК: 1 - Ж, 2 - М, 0 - х3)
        $user['city']        = (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['city']))        ? $userInfo['response'][0]['city']        : null;
        $user['screen_name'] = (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['screen_name'])) ? $userInfo['response'][0]['screen_name'] : null;
        $user['nickname']    = (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['nickname']))    ? $userInfo['response'][0]['nickname']    : null;
        $user['bdate']       = (isset($userInfo['response'][0]['bdate'])) ? $this->checkBirthday($userInfo['response'][0]['bdate']) : null;
        $user['soc_name']    = 'vk';

        return $user;
    }

    public function request($access_token, $method, $params)
    {
        $url = (($access_token) ? 'https://' : 'http://') . $this->requestUrl . $method;
        $params = array_merge(
            $params,
            array(
                'v' => '5.16',
                'lang' => 'ru',
            )
        );
        if($access_token)
            $params['access_token'] = $access_token;
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        return json_decode($response, true);
    }

    public function getToken($code,$url)
    {
        $params = array(
            'client_id'      => $this->app_id,
            'client_secret' => $this->secret_key,
            'code'          => $code,
            'redirect_uri'  => Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl($url, array(), 'http')
        );
        $url = 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token' . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $response_array = json_decode($response, true);
        if(isset($response_array['access_token']))
        {
            return $this->accessToken = $response_array;
        }
        return false;
    }

Контролллер:

    /** @var $socUser SocUsers * */

    if(isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        if($token = Yii::app()->vk->getToken($_GET['code'], 'socnetworks/vkAuth'))
        {
            $userInfo = Yii::app()->vk->getUserInfo($token['user_id']);

            $socUser = SocUsers::model()->findByAttributes(array(
                'token'    => md5('token_' . $userInfo['uid']),
                'soc_name' => $userInfo['soc_name']
            ));

            if($socUser == null)
                $socUser = $this->_saveUser($userInfo);

            $this->_loginUser($socUser);
        }
    }
```

Все работает, неоднократно проверено. Сравните, с вашим кодом, и лучше использовать для подобных целей объектный подход, упрощает тестирование и отладку и отлов ошибок.